# Вывод определенного кол-ва записей из массива

Tags: php

Привет.
Сейчас у меня выводится в случайном порядке записи из массива (файл)

```
<?php

$numbers = file("file.txt");
shuffle($numbers);
while (list(, $number) = each($numbers)) {
    echo "<br>", "$number";
}
?>
```

Как сделать вывод определенного кол-ва записей, а не всех записей из массива?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь функцией [array_slice](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-slice.php)

```
<?php

$numbers = file("file.txt");
shuffle($numbers);
$n = 5;
echo implode("<br/>\n", array_slice($numbers, 0, $n));
```

Либо вы можете остановиться в нужный момент с помощью `break`:

```
$i = 0;
foreach ($numbers as $num) {
   if (++$i == $n) break;
   echo $num."<br/>";
}
```

Либо воспользуйтесь циклом `for`:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $n && $i < count($numbers); $i++) {
  echo $numbers[$i]."<br/>";
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за развернутый ответ! <3